Compose key setting not recognized in 24.04
My 24.04 beta is now offically 23.04 LTS so I think I can now ask a question on AskUbuntu.  Although I have set the compose key to be Right-Alt in Settings, it is not applied.  Changing the selection has no effect either.  Is there a place where I can force the setting, e.g., is Settings suppose to modify a local equivalent of /etc/default/keyboard?
I've been pursuing this a bit more.  First thought was that my keyboard was failing---I switched it out for a new keyboard straight out of the box and the behaviour was the same.  I tried playing with alternative Compose Keys, e.g. PrtScr, and had it work for a few presses and then it stopped working.  Going back to setting the Compose Key to Right Alt I tried checking the keyboard with some of the on-line keyboard checkers. At Keyboard Checker (https://keyboardchecker.com/) pressing Right Alt was recognized with the response "Last Key Pressed was Compose".

Wait a few days. Ubuntu 24.04 is not yet released.

Mea culpa.  I've been using the old method (still working in 22.04) of entering accented characters (COMPOSE+[character] COMPOSE+[accent]) which is not the method described in current documentation and which no longer works.  It's now COMPOSE [accent] [character].
